# Using library that depends on ``this == window`` with webpack in strict mode

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

I use Angular2 which uses webpack under the hood, and I also use old library that assumes that `this` is is `window`.

I want to set `type: module` in my `package.json` and this will enable strict mode, so `this` wouldn't point to `window` after it.

Can I somehow configure webpack to mock/patch `this` for the certain library to make it point to `window`?

Comment: No. Just don't import that library as a module, add an old-fashioned `<script>` for it.

Comment: Which library is it?

Comment: an old plotly. I like idea of using ``script``, thank you. I wonder if this may also help: https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#granular-shimming

Comment: Can't you just upgrade plotly? It seems [they do support webpack bundling](https://plotly.com/javascript/getting-started/#webpack-user). But if that's not an option, yeah, `imports-loader?wrapper=window` might work as well, I didn't know this before!

Comment: @Bergi yes, I found this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotly.js-strict-dist-min